# $stmt-num_rows ( Return 0 )

Tags: php

i am just trying to learn prepared statement and i am following the PHP manual to guide me through, i have checked the answers regarding this problem on stackoverflow but, i can't find any solutions, the $stmt->num_rows always ( Return 0 )

there is a post on stackoverflow discussed the problem and they advised to use 
$stmt->store_result() just before the $stmt-num_rows, but the $stmt->num_rows return 0

some one please can tell me what i am doing wrong here.... i am just sick of the procedural style coding and i want to enhance my skills with prepared statement

here is the function down below

```
function get_all()
    {
        // ** Initializing  the Connection
        $mysqli = Connect();
        $sql = ( ' SELECT * FROM `users` ' );
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->get_result();
        echo $num_count = $stmt->num_rows();
        $user = array();
        for ($counter = 0; $row = $res->fetch_assoc(); $counter++) 
        {
            $user[$counter] = $row;
        }   
        return $user;
    }
```

// This is the second update

```
function get_all()
    {
        // ** Initializing  the Connection
        $mysqli = Connect();

        $sql = ( ' SELECT * FROM `users` ' );

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        $res = $stmt->get_result();

        echo $num_count = $stmt->num_rows;

        $user = array();

        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
             $user[] = $row;
        }


         return $user;

    }
```

// third update

```
function get_alll()
    {

        // ** Initializing  the Connection
        $mysqli = Connect();

        // no need to use * character, 
        // need to write query this way
        $sql = ( ' SELECT `id`,`fname`,`lname`,`uname`,`email` FROM `users` ' );

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        // here need to use bind param
        $stmt->bind_result( $id, $fname, $lname, $uname, $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        // it's important to store the result 
        // before using num rows    
        $res = $stmt->store_result();

        echo $num_count = $stmt->num_rows;

            // 
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo $fname;
        }

     }
```

Comment: Tip: the for() loop is not necessary: `while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) { $user[] = $row }` is all that's necessary.

Comment: Why do you need it anyway? You don't use it now and `count($user)` after the loop will tell you exactly how many there are.

Comment: thanks for the replay , i have changed to while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) { $user[] = $row } , but $stmt->num_rows returns 0 ,

Comment: jeron, what do you mean , I don't need it anyway, would you please be more clear....!

Answer (score 3):

`num_rows` is a property, not a method, try with `$stmt->num_rows` without brackets

Comment: thanks for the replay Uby, i have changed $stmt->num_rows without brackets but , it returns 0 ;) , any ideas

Comment: Not really, are you sure your query is correct and your table is not empty? Is your `$user` array filled with data?

Comment: yeah sure, uby, table is not empty, when i call the function get_all() and when i do var_dump i see 2 results, which the current data in the table , but $stmt->num_rows return 0

Comment: Can you update your code, so we read it?

Comment: I mean update your code in your answer. It's pretty difficult to read it on that comment ;)

Comment: sorry man, just updated it, above

Comment: hey Uby, just wanted to let you know it's works now, found some tips onlnine and the latest update of the function is above,