# Prepare statement row count

Tags: php, mysqli

I've made a class named SQL, inside of the class I have a function called Login(). I managed to make it work in the following way:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $con = $this->DbConnect();
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $username = strtolower($_POST['username']);
    $password_hash = sha1($password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$username' and password='$password_hash' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    //Login succes
    if ($count == 1) {
        echo "succes";
    }
}
```

I've tried it in the following way and could not manage to make it work, do you guys have any idea why?

UPDATE

```
 $con = $this->DbConnect();
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $username = strtolower($_POST['username']);
            $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $stmt = $this->DbConnect()->prepare("SELECT email,password FROM users WHERE email=? and password=? LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password_hash);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($username, $password_hash);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $count = $stmt->num_rows;
            var_dump($password_hash);
            echo $count;
            //Login succes
            if (password_verify($password, $password_hash)){
            }

            if ($count == 1){
//                header("location:");


            }else{
//                header("location:?error=1");
            }
```

Comment: both are bad, hash password properly. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Fix by removing two characters `()`, effectively a typo question.  Should have checked error logs and the php manual first.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551902/stmt-num-rows-return-0

Comment: ...also, you can use this syntax: `isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])` in your condition.... and `if($stmt->num_rows){`

Comment: Thanks i have solved it